# How do I get certain row in ROOM Database by month and year

Tags: android, sql, database, android-studio, android-room

I have a table where I put Date as long and when I convert it back to String it would be "dd/mm/yyyy". I want to fetch certain data with month and year, so the custom query would be like :

```
SELECT id FROM things 
   WHERE MONTH(happened_at) = 1 AND YEAR(happened_at) = 2009;
```

the example table has data like this :

| id | happend_at |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2009-01-01 12:08 |
| 2 | 2009-02-01 12:00 |
| 3 | 2009-01-12 09:40 |
| 4 | 2009-01-29 17:55 |

I'd like to know how to fetch data like that where the happened_at is in long and not String like the example above.

I'm currently learning to make android app using java and room database, so I made a converter to convert Date into long. The converter is like this :

```
import androidx.room.TypeConverter;
import java.util.Date;  
public class DateConverter {     
    @TypeConverter
         public static Date fromTimestamp(Long value) 
         {         return value == null ? null : 
            new Date(value);     
         }      
    @TypeConverter 
        public static Long dateToTimestamp(Date date) 
        {
                 return date == null ? null : 
                 date.getTime();
        } 
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate Dates should always be saved as dates in a database, so that all date functions can be used, what exactly means long, have  also sample data for that

Comment: sqlite, still no convertion needed or is recoemnded, please add new informatio  always i your question by using the edit link

Comment: so the inserted column would be like this **1659191466836**

Comment: that is no long it is called utc or Unix Timestamp C and for that exist a lot of conversion in sql or in java

Comment: I see, I didn't understand . So I still can use the query above? or maybe I'll have to change my query?

Comment: that depebds a lot on the rdms that you are using, but and column type, but for that you must check the documentation, but if you have Long as datatype you need to convert it

Comment: alright, thanks for helping me. I'll read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using :-

```
SELECT id FROM things WHERE CAST(strftime('%m',happened_at / 1000,'unixepoch') AS INTEGER) = 1 AND CAST(strftime('%Y',happened_at / 1000,'unixepoch') as INTEGER) = 2009;
```

This works because:-

- the value will be stored as a value that includes the milliseconds according to the TypeConverter as per
- > The [`getTime()`](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-date-gettime-method) method of Java Date class returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GTM which is represented by Date object.
- Dividing by 1000 strips the milliseconds which is then a Unix_Time values (seconds since 00:00:00 on 1st Jan 1970).
- [`strftime`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) is SQLite's date/time function and can be used for conversion/formatting dates from the recognised types (see link section 2)

The `unix_epoch` modifier, lets the SQLite `strftime` function discern between numbers being either Julian Day (without 'unixepoch' modifer) or Unix Time values (with the modifier).

- `'%m'` retrieves the month as a string padded with preceding 0's to always be 2 characters, `'%Y'` for the year part.
- see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html
- The [`CAST`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#cast_expressions) expression strips preceding 0's from the result should they exist i.e. converts 01 to 1.

  - an alternative to using CAST could be to force an integer (rather than string) value, say by adding 0 e.g. `SELECT id FROM things WHERE 0 + strftime('%m',happened_at / 1000,'unixepoch') = 1 AND 0 + strftime('%Y',happened_at / 1000,'unixepoch') = 2009;`

Comment: thank you so much for the answer, I'll try the query and come back if it works!